# Multi-database switching in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 databases defined in my YAML: **primary** and **datawarehouse**.

With the following code:

```
pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :datawarehouse) do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select 1')
end
pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
```

I would expect the output to be the same before and after the block and let it get back to the default.

However the output before gives me:

```
=> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :host=>"postgres", :encoding=>"unicode", :migrations_paths=>"db/migrate", :database=>"rails_devise_production"}
```

And the output after the block keeps the connection to the datawarehouse.

```
=> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :host=>"postgres-archive", :encoding=>"unicode", :migrations_paths=>"db/datawarehouse_migrate", :database=>"archive" }
```

How is this possible?  I would expect only the code in the block to be run against the other database connection.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a similar question](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37837) in Rails repo issues. In short, `connected_to` with `database` key is specifically for one-off connections, and you need to use the `role` key in your application.